# AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll not found

Tags: c#, sccm, sccm-2007

I recently installed "*Configuration_Manager_2012_R2_SDK_Setup.msi*", but when i try to build the samples which came with it, its showing a couple of references which are missing,

1. AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll
2. Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.dll
3. Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll

but I am only able to find "Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Messaging.dll: inside the installed folder location.

I am new to SCCM development any any help is appreciated.

Comment: Download the dll files and add it in references.

Comment: but is it safe to download dlls from internet ? It might be malicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a sample application project on MSDN : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-SCCM-Application-376c9124

All the required dlls are in the bin folder of this sample project.